# Opening debugging/project, it keeps just loading and loading

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Installed it like 1 hour ago, added some code and forms. Then wasted to test it out on browser with ctrl+F5 command and all I see is loading of the page.

http://pasteboard.co/1wumd89u.png

Reddit, what to do ._ .?

P.S: Tried to restart VS and change browsers. Did not helped.

Comment: Try a breakpoint as early as possible - Application_Start() from memory.

Comment: @christutty Sorry, but how do I exactly do it x_ x?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running the app via internal iis (casini). Using ctrl+F5 will run your app without any debugging support. Try using F5 only instead.

As christutty suggest put an early breakpoint. Select your Default.aspx file from the solution browser and hit F7, this will bring up the codebehind of your default page. You will see the page_load event, declare a variable like:

For C#  string myString = "Hello World!;
For VB myString As String = "Hello World!"

On the left side of that line click untill you get a red dot. Red dots are break point, mean that the debugging will stop the page execution. After you hit F5 and get to that break point hit F10 for each subsequent line, hit F11 if you enter into an external method.